# bring variable declared inside async task to different class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have pulled some information using newtonsoft.json and HttpClient:

```
public class Main {
    static async Task Main() {
        using(var client = new HttpClient() {
            url = "webapilink goes here";
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            apiStuff(the class i used to match the JSON format) variableName = 
                  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<apiStuff>(response);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the variable "variableName" to a seperate class, and for the life of me, cannot figure it out. I get an error when trying to use it anywhere outside of the HttpClient part.

Comment: Classes don't do anything unless you call a method. Methods take parameters. So you could for example pass `variableName` as a parameter to the class's method (or its constructor).

Comment: Can you please clarify what you expect as result of "get the variable 'variableName' to a seperate class"? Can't really see what it means to convert variable to class...

Comment: You're probably looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

Comment: You need to revisit scope in C#... Anything declared inside a method is not accessible outside of that method... this applies to block scopes as well... I would recommend you to pass some paramter `Main(ref apiStuff variableName)`... and then use it inside that method... and then declare that `variableName` inside your other class where you'll be using this `Main` method...

Comment: Can't this just _return_ the variable you want?  In the async/await pattern, that's `static async Task<apiStuff> Main() { ... do code ...; return variableName; }`. No reason to use `ref` if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your async method would return `void` if it was not async.  But it could be rewritten to return an instance of `apiStuff`, so that other methods (and other classes) could get that instance of `apiStuff` and use it:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MainClass
{
    public static async Task<apiStuff> Main()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string url = "webapilink goes here";
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            apiStuff variableName =
                  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<apiStuff>(response);
            return variableName;
        }
    }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public static async Task GetApiStuff()
    {
        apiStuff variableName = await MainClass.Main();
        // do more work with variableName
    }
}

public class apiStuff { /* defined elsewhere */ }
```

If this wasn't what you were asking about, please clarify in the original question.  (And I assume the method is not really named `Main` - could be confusing.)